# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

so I have a web app that runs correctly in localhost. However when I try to deploy it on a web server and try to log in I got the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://smis.wc.lt/login/loguser. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://ssmis.wc.lt' is therefore not allowed access.

My log-in code contains ajax on it. This is my code:

```
var login = function login(formdata){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: Main.Vars.host + 'login/loguser',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,   
        processData:false, 
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data){

            if(data.success == true){
                window.location.assign(Main.Vars.host + "home/");
            }else{
                alert("Cannot logged in!");
            }

        }

    });
};
```

I used CodeIgniter in backend. Thank you!

Comment: You need to read up on CORS, https://spring.io/understanding/cors

Comment: I put  header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin"'); on MY_Controller.php but it seems that it doesnt read it.

Comment: You need to put "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

on top of your PHP script.

Comment: I already put it on my controller class, but when I try to view my request on Network in browser, the header does not appear.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin only showed when I first load my page. However when I called method in my controller using ajax, the response does not contain Access-Control-Allow-Origin anymore. So I think there is a problem in ajax or something.

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin needs to be set in the requested resource. It does not matter if it is present in the page that sends the request.